# What is the difference between side-channel/regenerative/ring/vortex blowers?

Tags: machine-design, compressors, pneumatic, vacuum, vacuum-pumps

I am looking to write a Wikipedia article for side-channel blowers, but I have some big confusions that are not being alleviated by my attempts at research.

There are certainly two distinct ways that these are built. There is the type with rectangular fins on the impeller, which has a distinct circumferential gap around it and is within a large rounded-oblong channel. There is also the type with a semicircular finned channel in the impeller, matched with a semicircular side-channel to form two circular channels (there is one on either side of the impeller). There is no distinction in the naming and I have seen all four names used completely interchangeably with both types (Side-channel/regenerative/ring/vortex blowers). Both types are certainly in common usage (I even have one of each at work). Images of both below.

There seem to be few things that could be considered intermediate designs between the two. I have seen no variation of the circular channel type other than angling of the fins. For the rectangular finned type I have seen the root of the fins be concave and tapering to a point, which probably helps with turbulence and is fairly common, and also what looks like an absence of the circumferential gap, but I have only seen that in diagrams and not in photographs.

Is there any significant difference between these types in operation? The designs are so different that it seems like they would have different operating characteristics. With the plethora of names that are used I am getting the feeling that they may have had exclusive names originally, with the interchangeability of names occurring over time due to their characteristics being *similar enough* that both types can usually be used in the same operating conditions, even if there are some notable differences that would advantage one over the other for efficiency or such.

I guess it could just be a manufacturability and cost consideration that has lead to two different paths of design optimisation? It seems that the rectangular fin type might be easier to produce due to not needing tight circumferential and face tolerances on the outer edge of the impeller (the circular channel type has gaps of less than 0.5mm). I kinda doubt that this could be the full answer though, since it seems that both types are produced by expensive and high quality producers, but it does look like more of the cheap ones are the rectangular fin type.

So what I am ultimately looking for is any clues on an etymological difference between the names, and any knowledge on differences in operational characteristics. Any references would be greatly appreciated since that would be required for me to describe the info in an eventual Wikipedia article.

[image: semicircular finned channel][image: rectangular fins]